# Tablesorter, can I put the export button inside the thead?

Tags: tablesorter

can I put the export button inside the thead ? since outside is work, inside not. Thanks.

```
<table id="tableSorter">
<thead>
<tr>
  <th class="filter-false" data-sorter="false" colspan="3">Title
                <input type="button" class="ExportBtn" value="Export" /></th>
</tr>
<tr>
  <th>Col-1</th>
  <th>Col-2</th>
  <th>Col-3</th>
</tr>
</thead>
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer copied from the [opened issue](https://github.com/Mottie/tablesorter/issues/1114).

Use the class name set by the [`cssIgnoreRow` option](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/#cssignorerow) in the `tr`, like this:

```
<table id="RelatedCars">
<thead>
<tr class="tablesorter-ignoreRow">
  <th colspan="3">Title
    <input type="button" class="ExportBtn" value="Export" />
  </th>
</tr>
<tr>
  <th>Col-1</th>
  <th>Col-2</th>
  <th>Col-3</th>
</tr>
</thead>
```